# doctrine odm returns null for date field

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use symfony with doctrine mongodb odm. After persisting a document I got the right data in the db:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectID("565572731ba05cb40e000029"),
  "date": ISODate("2015-10-31T23:00:00.000Z"),
  "from": 10,
  "to": 18,
  "type": "work",
  "comment": "",
  "createdOn": ISODate("2015-11-25T08:33:55.000Z")
}
```

But when I try to fetch the data in my repository, it returns null as the value of the date field.

*edit: I deleted the "createdOn" (also a date type field) and after it worked fine. But when I had two date fields again in my document, it returned NULL, but now for the "createdOn" field.

```
object(AppBundle\Document\Report)#636 (10) {
  ["id":protected]=>
  string(24) "565572731ba05cb40e000029"
  ["date":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["from":protected]=>
  int(10)
  ["to":protected]=>
  int(18)
  ["type":protected]=>
  string(4) "work"
  ["comment":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["createdOn":protected]=>
  object(DateTime)#572 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2015-11-25 09:33:55.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
  }
```

}

I tried it with different field name (assuming the "date" is reserved) but the result is the same. 
Does anyone have idea why is it NULL?

My document class:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="report", repositoryClass="AppBundle\Document\ReportRepository")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks 
*/
class Report {

    /** @MongoDB\Id */
    protected $id;

    /** @MongoDB\date */
    protected $date;

    /** @MongoDB\int */
    protected $from;

    /** @MongoDB\int */
    protected $to;

    /** @MongoDB\string */
    protected $type;

    /** @MongoDB\string */
    protected $comment;

    /** @MongoDB\date */
    protected $createdOn;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\PrePersist()
     * @MongoDB\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function prePersist() {
        $this->setCreatedOn(new \DateTime());
    }
```

... and of course the (generated) getters and setters. And "createdOn" is a also date field and it returns the right values.

Comment: Provide your entity class.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear the cache :

> php app/console c:c

Comment: PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '&' in /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini on line 107
Could not open input file: app/console